# How to use local source instead of jar file in chrome.manifest in Mozilla application

Tags: javascript, xul

I want to change some codes in zotero application, so i extracted jar codes in a directory for debug convenience. Therefor needs change links in chrome.manifest file too. but when this line changed, I'm getting error and the application get stuck. How can I change chrome.manifest to my directory?

`content  zotero  jar:zotero.jar!/chrome/content/zotero/   contentaccessible=yes`